# How do you create a list of Tensors from a single Tensor in Tensorflow and the other way around

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I have played around a bit with lists of tensors that you get i.e. from Keras models when calling model.trainable_variables and hit a wall. What is the best way to convert this list to a single flat tensor (a Vector) so i can calculate tf.norm()'s and the other way around? Especially putting elements of a single one-dimensional vector back into a list of tensors with certain shapes seems to give trouble. What i came up with so far:

```
#Converts a list of tensors to a single vectorlike tensor
def to_vector(list):
    new_list = []
    for element in list:
        new_list.append(tf.reshape(element, shape=(tf.size(element))))
    return tf.concat(new_list, axis=0)


#Convert a Tensor of shape (X,) into a list of Tensors [ (A,B,..), (C,D)] that is similar to old_list
def to_list(vector, old_list):
    offset = tf.constant(0)
    new_list = []
    i = tf.constant(0)
    for i in range(0,len(old_list)):
        slice = tf.slice(vector, [offset], [tf.size(old_list[i])])
        new_list.append(tf.reshape(slice, shape=old_list[i].shape))
        offset = offset + tf.size(old_list[i])
    return new_list
```

The forward propagation works fine, but the backward pass in the ''to_list'' function seems to fail. I tried it with Tensorflow control structures, but the while loop does not execute, since i change the size of the loop variable.

```
def to_list(vector, old_list):
    offset = tf.constant(0)
    new_list = []
    i = tf.constant(0)
    condition = lambda i, offset, n_list: tf.less(i, len(old_list))
    def body(i, offset, n_list):
        slice = tf.slice(vector, [offset], [tf.size(old_list[i])])
        n_list.append(tf.reshape(slice, shape=old_list[i].shape))
        tf.add(i,1)
        tf.add(offset, tf.size(old_list[i]))
        return i, offset, n_list


    final_i, final_offset, final_n_list = tf.while_loop( condition, body, (i,offset, new_list ))
    return final_n_list
```

Is there an easy way to do this, that i do not know about? Is there any way to make those functions backpropagatable?